# Entity Model Issue in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I'm facing issues when accessing the Entity Model object in my classes. This is the first time I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and I'm thinking that there may be some changes related to this problem. Somehow when I'm accessing the Entity Model object only the table models are being listed. I'm not able to access any properties or methods of the object.

[image: Intellisense example]

I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong, I'm doing the exact things that I used to do on Visual Studio 2010 with no problems whatsoever.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you using Code-First ? Can you paste the code of DatabaseEntities ?

Comment: Also if you're using code first, are the attributes that you're "missing" declared with `public` visibility?

Comment: No I'm not using Code-First I simply created the database and then generated the model using the created database. Like I've said I've done this before with no problems.

Comment: What does `DatabaseEntities` derive from? Is it `DbContext`? Do you have a reference to `System.Data` in your project?

Comment: I managed to solve it, the issue is because of the Code Generation Strategy in the Entity Model properties. By default in Visual Studio 2010 it is set to default but in 2012 it is not, apart from changing it from None to Default the two .tt created files should be deleted.

Refer to these this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556581

Comment: What I'd like to know is the difference between deriving the context from `ObjectContext` and entity classes that are dervived from `EntityOjbect` to deriving the context from `DBContext` and POCO entity classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2010 would generate by default an `ObjectContext` based context and `EntityObject` based entities. VS2012 generates by default a `DbContext` based context and POCO based entities. You can change the default by flipping "Code Generation Strategy" in the properties. In VS2012 "Default" will generate `ObjectContext` and `EntityObject` while "None" will use T4 templates (which by default will generate `DbContext` and POCO). Note that when going from "None" to "Default" you will probably need to remove T4 templates (.tt files) or you may end up with two sets of entities - POCO and EntityObject based.

`DbContext` is a streamlined API built on top of `ObjectContext` and - along with POCO entities - is a preferred way of working with Entity Framework these days. There are some lower level things you may not be able to do with `DbContext` in which case you can drop down to `ObjectContext` by using `IObjectContextAdapter` like this:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)dbCtx).ObjectContext
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For now I'm going to stick to the 'old way' of doing it, i.e. using the `ObjectContext` and `EntityObject` as I'm comfortable with this method. I'll try to research more on how to use the other method, since it's the preferred way of working with Entity Framework.

Comment: If you are starting from scratch you may want to take a look at EF6. From the tooling perspective EF6 is supported in VS2013 Preview and there is a replacement for the tooling that originally shipped with VS2012. Find more details here http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/06/08/ef-designer-now-supports-ef6/ and here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/06/26/ef-and-visual-studio-2013-preview.aspx. Note that new tooling supports both EF5 and EF6 and that it is currently a Beta release.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I'll try to check it out soon! :)